# helo_dynamic_ipaddr error and spam email

Tags: email, spam, mail

I'm trying to send an email from my domain's email which is hosted on a cpanel (without support) but I always get it in the spam folder (I send it to my gmail account for my test but here I am using a test tool for the purpose of detection of spam scores), I'm sending a nice example :

Subject:

```
Welcome to Dream World Holding
```

Body:

```
Hi Steve Moretz, Welcome to our website we wish you a happy time and 
good memories.

With regards, Dream World Holding
```

full source:

```
Received: by mail-tester.com (Postfix, from userid 500)
    id 01CD3A996B; Tue,  9 Aug 2022 21:11:40 +0200 (CEST)
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.2 (2018-09-13) on mail-tester.com
X-Spam-Level: ***
X-Spam-Status: No/3.0/5.0
X-Spam-Test-Scores: CK_HELO_GENERIC=0.001,DKIM_SIGNED=0.1,DKIM_VALID=-0.1,
    DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1,DKIM_VALID_EF=-0.1,HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR=3.243,
    SPF_HELO_NONE=0.001,SPF_PASS=-0.001,URIBL_BLOCKED=0.001
X-Spam-Last-External-IP: 5.9.198.252
X-Spam-Last-External-HELO: static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de
X-Spam-Last-External-rDNS: static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de
X-Spam-Date-of-Scan: Tue, 09 Aug 2022 21:11:40 +0200
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  0.0 CK_HELO_GENERIC Relay used name indicative of a Dynamic Pool or
    *       Generic rPTR
    *  0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was
    *      blocked.  See
    *      http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
    *      for more information.
    *      [URIs: dreamworldestate.com]
    * -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
    *  0.0 SPF_HELO_NONE SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record
    *  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
    *       valid
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
    *      author's domain
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
    *      envelope-from domain
    *  3.2 HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR Relay HELO'd using suspicious hostname (IP
    *      addr 1)
Received-SPF: Pass (sender SPF authorized) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=5.9.198.252; helo=static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de; envelope-from=info@dreamworldestate.com; receiver=test-m80jezfhc@srv1.mail-tester.com 
DMARC-Filter: OpenDMARC Filter v1.3.1 mail-tester.com 3D22EA9560
Authentication-Results: mail-tester.com; dmarc=pass header.from=dreamworldestate.com
Authentication-Results: mail-tester.com;
    dkim=pass (2048-bit key; unprotected) header.d=dreamworldestate.com header.i=@dreamworldestate.com header.b=CDvs6F4X;
    dkim-atps=neutral
Received: from static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de (static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de [5.9.198.252])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail-tester.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 3D22EA9560
    for <test-m80jezfhc@srv1.mail-tester.com>; Tue,  9 Aug 2022 21:11:39 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=dreamworldestate.com; s=default; h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:
    Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:MIME-Version:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-ID:
    Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc
    :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
    List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
    bh=UtKoZUk/AeHB9MhbSdOHAhupqHz/Hir5jeQJQvfelME=; b=CDvs6F4XG5umLCw9QFTswSLZ6+
    2JdKbc5x18pJyuClQcXv/CiDjwOm5Y2vCsj4c3wj9Vb2rOLDnzle0zc3CYs2tDDmE8f7rnsdGSFCO
    CrTbMahEh8RbO6eoCZ4Kvt0UVEoJ6IFlyhX+En+mZ/fBIn1XMMAuhHtGE5SiKMCLBxDE2zIBdprQz
    Pr1ttNpUCZj3yVkm6y8WHTcsENnvuBYc4QgweYLIoU1/o/tCEmecg9sP8gsInxB0Z8wlnEtW5jk/K
    hwLcPZMkfLgVn9tbCT5wn4vXOUtKYq0gS2N6OcZXaYjbwxzQ3QjPF263p/tnUr075H2gM+A3BOcrP
    REUAlS0w==;
Received: from [::1] (port=50122 helo=static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de)
    by static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de with esmtpa (Exim 4.95)
    (envelope-from <info@dreamworldestate.com>)
    id 1oLUde-0004lA-Gx
    for test-m80jezfhc@srv1.mail-tester.com;

    Tue, 09 Aug 2022 15:11:38 -0400
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2022 15:11:38 -0400
From: info@dreamworldestate.com
To: test-m80jezfhc@srv1.mail-tester.com
Subject: Welcome to Dream World Holding
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.5.2
Message-ID: <6fa6c5010a5f2827519a0a2dd68b5c53@dreamworldestate.com>
X-Sender: info@dreamworldestate.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - srv1.mail-tester.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - dreamworldestate.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de: authenticated_id: info@dreamworldestate.com
X-Authenticated-Sender: static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de: info@dreamworldestate.com
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 

Hi Steve Moretz, Welcome to our website we wish you a happy time and 
good memories.

With regards, Dream World Holding

Hi Steve Moretz, Welcome to our website we wish you a happy time and 
good memories.

With regards, Dream World Holding
```

Here's the test results : https://www.mail-tester.com/test-m80jezfhc

HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR is the main problem it mentions : Relay HELO'd using suspicious hostname (IP addr 1).

In my mail delivery section in panel it mentions: Mail HELO static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de

It also says: REVERSE DNS (PTR) is okay and is, 252.198.9.5.in-addr.arpa. -> static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de.

I have tried recreating all the PTR, DKIM, SPF records but nothing was helpful, I'm really lost here.

---

Update: forgot to mention that the server's hostname is: static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de and it's ip address is: 5.9.198.252

also for its ip the following is set:

```
Type    Domain Name TTL     Canonical Name
PTR     5.9.198.252 21600   static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de.
```

Answer (score 0):

Kudos for getting SPF, DKIM and DMARC set up. However SMTP has been thoroughly broken by people trying to do the right thing by their customers. Everyone invents their own rules for how to accept email. You have some good feedback from mail-tester.com but that doesn't automatically mean that fixing those issues will improve your IPR at Google. Having said that, I do suspect that fixing your hostname will improve matters somewhat.

There's still lots of people advocating RMX - even though it has been thoroughly deprecated (actually never ratified as a standard). But using something more specific to your organization than "static.252.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de" would likely help. If this is a send-only MTA, implementing a very low priority MX record as well as a A record would be advisable. If your provider can update the PTR record, that would be a big help.

I've only a little (and bad) experience with Exim - so I can't advise how to configure this in your MTA - but I'm sure there will be instructions on the internet somewhere (Sendmail and Postfix use /etc/mailname).